# Create ttf with a set of chars from other font

Tags: pdf, fonts, pdf-generation, prawn

Im programming an app that generates PDFs for several situations. In some of them there are greek letters that should be displayed. My Problem is that including a font like arial that provides these chars adds some mb to my pdfs because the whole font is included in the pdf.

Is there a way to include just the chars needed or to generate a "new" font that only includes the chars needed as another font?

Comment: Its called subsetting a font. Many PDF generation applications support it. Since you are writing your own, your would need to read the PDF Specification on how to subset fonts.

Comment: Thanks for info, i looked it up in the prawn documentation it seems to be a feature of prawn. Post as answer and I will accept it as correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is font subsetting. This is normally a function of the code making the pdf.